# Overlay view over tab viewcontrollers

Tags: iphone

using iphone sdk 4.1. I want to overlay a small view over all my tabcontroller views. this will present itself on the push of a button from one of the tab bar viewcontrollers but then i wish it to remain in place even if the user tabs to another view. How to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the Apple docs for UITabViewController - you want to add your overlay as a subview of the "view" property on your UITabViewController. This will make it appear above everything on the screen (even over the tab-bar itself, if you're not careful).

You can change the tabs as much as you want - that should just switch the value of the content underneath.